# Edit value of a tag in sysrepo using single command , want to automate , so a single command is required

Tags: linux, terminal, automation, command, command-line-interface

I want to edit a tag in xml of sysrepo store i tried --edit but it opens the editor . I want to edit the tag using a single command . I tried this but got verbosity error and sometimes missing argument error .
sysrepoctl --change-data --module example-module --xpath /example-module:container/example-module:leaf-node --value "new_value"
any example solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are missing is some xpath key. Example module:container/example-module:leaf-node[key=‘val’] so this way you can edit the one specific leaf that corresponds to that path, otherwise it can be ambiguous